# pandas.where with different shapes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was reading about the pandas dataframe [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) function.

But I want to compare two dataframes with different shapes, e.g:

```
>>>print(df1.shape)
(10495, 12)
>>>print(df2.shape)
(10488, 12)
```

Is there a function similar to `where` to deal with this condition?

Best,

Comment: You may think about updating your question with [mcve]. It will definitely help people wanting to assist you in resolving your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same as what you are doing, but I recently had to do a comparison of disparately shaped dataframes as so:

```
df1['col2'].mask(df1['col1] == df2.loc[0, 'col1'])
```

In my example df1 and df2 have different numbers of rows.  This returns back a population from df1.col2 where col1 is the same between the two dataframes.

The other option is to merge the dataframes.

Let me know if it works!